# Is it possible to have an async message receiver in Spring AMQP that handles multiple content types?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using an asyncronous message receiver in Spring-AMQP to receive messages. Currently only messages with JSON content are handled, but I have a requirement to also handle messages with XML content. My current implementation of `MessageListener` has a `MessageConverter` injected and uses it in `onMessage(Message)`, like this:

```
MyMessage myMessage = (MyMessage) jsonConverter.fromMessage(message);
```

In order to support different content types I could obviously use the `MessageProperties` to interrogate the content-type header and manually select a converter to use. But that seems like a lot of work, like Spring should provide some better support for this scenario. I was hoping to find a generic `MessageConverter` implementation that would map from content-types to specific converters, but there doesn't seem to be such a thing.

Is my best option to write a delegating converter like that? Or is there a way to configure the `ListenerContainer` to support both async receiving *and* multiple converters that are automatically used as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an [open JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-138) issue requesting support for a CompositeMessageConverter.

The listener container doesn't support conversion but we do have the `MessageListenerAdapter` which does support them (but just one, and has other stuff like handling replies).

Using the adapter means you can use a POJO method on your listener...

```
public void handleMessage(MyObject foo) {...}
```

If you put a delegating converter (one that delegates to either the json or marshalling converter) into the `MLA`, and both converters create the same object type, this will work fine. Otherwise the signature would have to take an `Object` and you'd have to do `instanceof` tests.

At some point, I'd like to make the adapter a bit smarter so it can choose the method based on the object type created by the converter...

```
public void handleMessage(Foo foo) {...}

public void handleMessage(Bar bar) {...}
```

... but that's really a different issue.

If you come up with a useful converter that you would like to contribute to the framework, the guidelines are [on the project wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/wiki).

Comment: Thanks, @gary-russel. Just to make sure I understand clearly, you're saying that the only option right now is to write a delegating/composite converter that chooses based on message content type. Correct?

Comment: I do have a basic delegating converter working; it's almost trivial, so reviewing and following the project guidelines is going to take longer than actually writing it ;-) Oh, and I have to write some unit tests, too. So I'd love to contribute it, but it's probably going to be unlikely right now.

Comment: How to handle Message type using Adapter ? It was working when I was using String, but as soon as I changed it to Message, I am getting exception Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.my.myObject.myMethod([B)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
 at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:178)
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:466)
 ... 12 more

Comment: The adapter is for, err, adapting messages. If you want to get the message itself, implement `MessageListener.onMessage()`.

Comment: I added some code to the JIRA issue; see https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-138?focusedCommentId=111198&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-111198