# How to use pojo with Message type parameter in spring amqp using MessageListenerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.stockopedia.symfony.Foundation.importExchange([B)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:466)
    ... 12 more
```

This is how I am sending messages

```
        MessageProperties props = MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
                .setReplyTo(this.replyQueue)
                .setCorrelationId(itemStr.getBytes())
                .setHeader("replyTimeout", this.replyTimeout).build();

        Message message = MessageBuilder
                .withBody(item.toString().getBytes()).andProperties(props)
                .build();
```

This is my listener container configuration

```
<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="${import.exchanges.listener.concurrency}"
    requeue-rejected="false" prefetch="1" >
    <rabbit:listener queues="${import.exchanges.shares.queue}"
        ref="foundation" method="importExchange" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

This is my pojo,

```
public class Foundation {   
    public Message importExchange(Message exchange) {
        System.out.println("Command:" + exchange.getBody());        
                Message message = MessageBuilder
                .withBody(exchange.getBody().toString().getBytes()).setCorrelationId(exchange.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId()                                  .toString().getBytes()).build();

        return message; 
    }
}
```

I dont want to implement any interfaces as I have many such methods in same pojo which I want to use as listeners.

I have seen MessageListenerAdapter implemention code, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/adapter/MessageListenerAdapter.java and docs  http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/adapter/MessageListenerAdapter.html

Here this example is given which accepts Message argument

```
 public interface RawMessageDelegate {
        void handleMessage(Message message);
 }
```

My pojo is similar, why I am getting this exception ? I have tried removing setContentType but still getting same exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I replied to your comment in [Is it possible to have an async message receiver in Spring AMQP that handles multiple content types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235312/is-it-possible-to-have-an-async-message-receiver-in-spring-amqp-that-handles-mul/22236635#comment36493164_22236635) it is not currently possible using the standard adapter; you have to implement `MessageListener.onMessage()` to get the message.

We are considering enhancing the adapter to allow such arguments, as I mentioned in my answer to that same question.

EDIT:

Or, if you need to do request/reply, you can still use the adapter but you need to set the message converter property to `null`.

In that case, though, your reply must also be a `Message`, the adapter can't convert it for you.

If you want to receive a message but return an object for conversion, you would need to write a custom converter.

When using a customized `MessageListenerAdapter`, you need to define the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` as a `<bean/>` instead of using the `<rabbit:listener-container/>` element.

Define a bean for your listener, a bean for the adapter with a reference to your bean (and a null message converter), and a bean for the container with a reference to the adapter.

Comment: If I implement MessageListener, onMessage should return void. In my case, I need to return Object ? How do I do that ?

Comment: I edited my answer with a work-around, but I do agree we should enhance the adapter.